# Error in updating a SQL Server Express database in windows forms

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-express

This is my problem:

I am creating an application in C# using Visual Studio 2010. In one of the modules of the application, I have to update an existing table and insert into another table. Both tables are created.

Problem is when I don't close the total application, it updates and inserts into the tables perfectly, but when I close the application and open it again all the values are reset.

I think that only the data set is being updated and not the actual database.

I want to know how to actually update the database.

My code looks somewhat like this:

```
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con;                      
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd,cmd1,cmd2;

    private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\pharmacy.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
        con.Open();
        MessageBox.Show("Connection successful!");
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cmd1 = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("Select med_id from stock where med_id= " + textBox1.Text + ";", con);
        object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        if (result == null)
        {
            cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("insert into stock values('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "','" + textBox3.Text + "','" + textBox4.Text + "','" + textBox5.Text + "','" + textBox6.Text + "','" + textBox7.Text + "','" + textBox8.Text + "','" + textBox9.Text + "');", con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        else
        {
            cmd2 = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("alter table stock set current_stock = (select current_stock from stock where med_id=" + textBox1.Text + ";) + "+ textBox8.Text +" where med_id="+textBox1.Text+";",con);
         }
            cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();     
    }
```

Comment: Can you spell [SQL injection attacks?!?!?](http://xkcd.com/327/) - you should **never** concatenate together a SQL statement - [use **parametrized queries** instead](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/AdoDotNet/Lesson06.aspx) - **always**

Answer (score 0):

As usual - upon running, Visual Studio makes a **copy** of your database file. Then, you work with that copy, you update records there. When you invoke the application again, the original file is copied **over** the one you made changes into.

Comment: there are at least few options. 1) select the database file in your vs project, change "Copy Always" to "Copy Never" and manually copy your database to the data directory. 2) copy your database to another folder in your OS, outside of the VS project and update your connection string to point to a fixed location on your hard disk. 3) use SQL Management Studio to manually attach the database file to the server and then create a new connection with the Server Explorer in the VS and use the connection string that points to the database on the server rather than the one which attaches the file

Comment: can you just tell me how to "manually copy your database to the data directory", I din't get that part.

Comment: If I remember correctly, the DataDirectory would be a shortcut for the location of your executable file, in this case \bin\Debug or \bin\Release (depending on the build options). Copy the file manually there and remember to change it to "Copy Never" under the solution. This way everytime the same database file will be used, the one from the \bin\Debug.

Answer (score 0):

These steps worked for me, I'm using Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop:

Step 1: 
Go to database explorer, 
right click database name (mdf file), 
select modify connections, 
select Browse, 
within your project folder, go into the bin folder, then go into the Debug folder,
select the mdf file in the debug folder,
select Test Connection to ensure connection succeeds, then click OK

Next, go to properties of the database (mdf file),
click the connection string box in the properties explorer menu,
copy the data source file path in the connection string box

Step 2:
In the Solutions Explorer box, double click 'Properties',
go to Settings option,
Insert Name - (can be anything you want, I named mine EmployeeConnString)
Insert Type - In the dropdown box, select connection string
Insert Scope - in the dropdown box, select application
Insert Value - right-click paste (previously copied file path), press enter
You can exit this tab

Step 3:
Go back to the solutions explorer box and select the database file in your vs project(mdf file),
Go to the properties explorer window to the copy to output directory option,
change "Copy Always" to "Copy Never" or "Do Not Copy",

These steps worked for me and now everything I enter updates correctly, as well as when i re-run the application, the updated data shows in the new form box.